# How to remove a specific character from data values?

Tags: r

In a column, I have many numerical values where its followed by * , examples :- 108*, 64* etc. I just need to remove the * symbol from these values. basically it should look like 108, 64.

Comment: Provide some sample data using `dput()` and paste the result into your question. You probably have a character vector so using `gsub()` followed by `as.integer()` will get you there.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(sub("\\*", "", x))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a vector `x`.

```
x = c("108*", "64*", "10*")
x
```

First, you have to remove the "*". Then, you have to convert it to a numeric vector as you can observe (using `typeof(x)`) that it is a character vector right now).

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
   gsub("*", "", ., fixed = TRUE) %>%
   as.numeric()
```

`gsub()` is a function that replaces a pattern with another pattern. I'm specifying `fixed = TRUE` because I want to match "*" alone (else it'll consider a regex.

To be honest, you don't need `tidyverse`. But I prefer this over nested codes for better readability.

---

If this answers your question, please accept it and close the topic!